# Function not defined error reactjs

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs

I have one function in Action file and need to call it from componenent file with parameters but while calling it, its giving error for function not defined

**Component Code :**

```
    handleClick(e){

         addinput({input1:this.refs.inp1.value,input2:this.refs.inp2.value}) // This function I have defined in action file

      }
```

**Action file code :**

```
export function addinput(myval1) {
 return {
   type: 'ADD_INPUT',
   payload: myval1
 };
}
```

**I am getting below error in console**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addinput is not defined
```

Whats I am doing wrong here !!

Comment: If this is a Redux setup you should probably use dispatch to "communicate" the action to the store. The error here is probably due to a missing "import addinput from './path/to/action/file'" statement.

Comment: I have imported it already in this file :

import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import  Button  from "./Button";
import  bindActionCreators  from 'redux'
import  * as TodoActionCreators from "../actions/countActions";

addinput function is in action/counaction file 

Is there any other thing I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is import the function from action file in your component like

```
import {addinput} from './path/to/action'
```

and I am assuming your usiong redux, you can bind the action to props with connect and `bindActionCreators` function

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'

...

class MyComponentName extends React.Component{

  handleClick = (e) => {
        this.props.addinput({input1:this.refs.inp1.value,input2:this.refs.inp2.value}) 

      }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
     return bindActionCreators({addInput}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponentName)
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham !! It was actually defined in other main App component and I missed to dispatch from there!! Its working fine now !! Thank you again !!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Could your accept this as an answer if it helped :)